# Copy row data from one workbook to another based on row header name in the first column

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a table mapping the row names in my Destination workbook to row names in my source sheet in the sheet named 'Test'. It is as follows :

MAP:

[image]

The destination rows are not successive and there are other rows in between not referring data from the source sheet. The row names in the source sheet are in Column 2 and row names in Destination sheet are in column 1. I need to copy the data from the source sheet rows that have matching name in the Destination sheet rows as per my mapping from the image attached.

This is my code:

```
Sub Map()


DestName = "Data Cost Estimate"        'Name of destination sheet
SourceName = "EST Actuals"             'Name of Source sheet
MyDir = "Default directory path"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set HeadWS = Wb.Worksheets("Test")

With HeadWS
    LastHead = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set HeadRange = .Range("A2:A" & LastHead)
    ReDim Heads(LastHead - 2) '-1 for header row in header map and -1 for 0 based arrary
    Heads = HeadRange.Value
End With

 answer = MsgBox("If you want to select a specific file click Yes, if you want to go to default path and If you are not sure, click Cancel", vbYesCancel + vbQuestion, "User Specified Path")
    If answer = vbYes Then

    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

    wkb.Worksheets(SourceName).Copy

With wkb.Worksheets(SourceName)
     '.Cells.UnMerge 'uncomment this line if you want merged cells to be unmerged
    'HeadRow = .Columns(1).Find("Brand Title").Row
    '.Rows("1:" & HeadRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    For j = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(1, j), Heads, False)) Then .Columns(j).Delete
    Next
    HeadRange.Offset(, 1).Copy
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
End With
ThisWorkbook.Save

ElseIf answer = vbCancel then

Msgbox "Do nothing"
Exit Sub

End If

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With


End Sub
```

I think it would be easier if I write a function for this process, but I am not sure as to how.
The table mapping is in columns A,B respectively.
Thank you

Comment: What is your question? Is your code working? Are you looking for an alternative way?

Comment: My code is not working and I also want to write a function for this @Pierre44